# How to deal with: Error: could not find function "read_csv"

Tags: r

I installed the package `readr` and tried to upload a `.csv` file in Rstudio.
When I try to load this package I get the following error:

```
> library(readr)
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), 
versionCheck   = vI[[j]]) : there is no package called ‘hms’ In addition:
Warning message: Paket ‘readr’ wurde unter R Version 3.2.5 erstellt 
Error: Laden von Paket oder Namensraum für ‘readr’ fehlgeschlagen
```

When I try to upload the `.csv` file in R I get the error:

```
> dataX<-read_csv("file.csv")
 Error: could not find function "read_csv"
```

The result of  `sessionInfo()` is:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

 loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.3-2 scales_0.4.1     R6_2.2.2   lazyeval_0.2.0            plyr_1.8.4      
 [6] tools_3.2.2      gtable_0.2.0     tibble_1.3.0     Rcpp_0.12.10      ggplot2_2.2.1   
 [11] grid_3.2.2       munsell_0.4.3
```

I will appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: The package didn't load, so the `read_csv` function isn't in your environment. It looks like the package load failed because you're missing a dependency `hms`, so perhaps see if installing `hms` resolves the issue.

Comment: What is the error, can you provide your `sessioninfo()`?

Comment: @Technophobe01. I put the result of  `sessionInfo()` on the edit of my question.

Comment: @cmaher.  I followed your advice.I got a new error massage though:  `ERROR: dependency 'rlang' is not available for package 'hms' Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘hms’ had non-zero exit status`.

Comment: @user249018 - looking at your R version 3.2.2 and the package you are trying to install I would recommend you first upgrade R to a newer version. For example R Version 3.4.4. This may be a contributing factor. See notes in the answer on Windows package setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I was able to duplicate the problem on Windows. How and Why?

### Resolution - Install R3.4.4

#### How

- Install [R3.4.4](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/R-3.4.4-win.exe)
- Install [Rtools3.4](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/Rtools34.exe).
- Launch R
  `> install.packages("readr")`

#### Why?

The issue here (appears to be) that readr and the [TidyVerse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) packages require later versions of R than R3.2.2. and the WIndows Rtools you have. I was able to duplicate the issue described by installing R3.2.2 and [RTools3.2](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/Rtools32.exe) and then trying to instal readr.

I did not encounter the error on installation of R3.4.4.

#### Background on Upgrading R on Windows:

You can install multiple versions of R (*Base environment*) and R Tools (*Development environment)* on Windows. My personal recommendation is to uninstall R, install the new versions of R, then install the latest R Tools and copy over the libraries per Windows faq below.

- [R Windows FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html)

2.8 What’s the best way to upgrade?

That’s a matter of taste. For most people the best thing to do is to uninstall R (see the previous Q), install the new version, copy any installed packages to the library folder in the new installation, run `update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE, ask=FALSE)` in the new R and then delete anything left of the old installation. Different versions of R are quite deliberately installed in parallel folders so you can keep old versions around if you wish.

For those with a personal library (folder `R\win-library\x.y` of your home directory, `R\win64-library\x.y` on 64-bit builds), you will need to update that too when the minor version of R changes (e.g. from 3.0.2 to 3.1.0). A simple way to do so is to copy (say) `R\win-library\3.0` to `R\win-library\3.1` before running `update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE, ask=FALSE)`.

Comment: Thanks. What should I do first: upgrade R or follow the other steps you suggest ? I have never upgraded a software, so I dont want to make a mistake.

Comment: Here is what I get concerning the .libpath: `> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/absolution/Documents/R/win-library/3.2"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/library"   `. I also tried to do the Installation of ´readr´  including the dependencies, but I got the same error that I displayed in the edit of my question.

Comment: I did the first step. The choice 1 is called: `0-Cloud [https]`, and the choice `35: Germany (Göttingen) [https] `. Since I am in Germany should I really set to 1 and not 35 ?

Comment: I followed your suggestions, but the same problem persists.

Comment: Many thanks for your efforts. For the purpose of this issue, should I install R3.4.4. first and then uninstall the old version, or should I upgrade the old version using the package `installr` and then the command `updataR()` ?

Comment: See updated answer - FYI R has great user documentation and FAQ's. I add the linked to the relevant materials.

Comment: Thanks. When I open the libraries of both, the unistalled (old) version and the installed version, I dont see which are the packages in the old version to be copied, since it all looks the same in both versions. Can you tell me how do I know which packages should I copy from the old Version into the new one ?

Comment: The version number is in the library path. Do a `.libpaths()` in each version of R and copy from one to the other. i.e. `xcopy /s "C:/Users/absolution/Documents/R/win-library/3.2" "C:/Users/absolution/Documents/R/win-library/3.4"`

Comment: This is overkill, I think. See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I too had the similar problem and re-installing package "tidyverse" did the trick for me while I was already on 3.4.4 version of R.

Answer (score -1):

For me, it was loading `tidyverse` into the environment that did the trick. Load both tidyverse and dplyr